# iCloud won't let me in using a third party app

Tags: icloud, password

I don't know what I am doing. I don't have access to my iPad at the moment because it won't charge so I don't have an apple device to fix this.

Just today I go to retrieve some important emails and I have a notification that my account has incorrect username or password info. I can't imagine since I have had the same one for 10 years so I reentered it. Same message.

I have a windows and 2 Android devices all of which have this account on it and is set to open without a password because my devices have passwords.

The same on all of them so I didn't enter an incorrect password. Help!!!

Comment: I'm new to this so might be answering wrong but I have my i cloud email in several apps, Gmail, email on Android and 2 windows devices and all have worked fine with the only password I ever used for about 10 years. I thought it was the device that kicked out the info but all devices have shut it out and won't take the only password I ever used, I never changed it from the original

Comment: I did set it up from an iPhone years ago but I had to switch to an Android because everytime something went wrong with it the only Apple store is 80 miles and I wouldn't have a phone because I couldn't get there. My iPad just stopped charging 2 months ago so I don't have a working Apple device to resort to

Comment: check my answer... you can fix this easily... no need for an Apple device or to got to a store...

Comment: I run an online business with this is my primary email and I am starting to lose my mind because I can't fill orders without the information and I have to pay penalties of 25% on orders not shipped in 48 hours and I can't even get the contact info. Something has happened that I didn't do but I don't know what triggered it because I have never had a problem with anything before

Comment: One more time, read my answer!

Comment: I just figured out how to get to your answer, I am often embarrassed not to know certain things, I am going to try that right now, thank you

Comment: Did my answer fix your problem?

Answer (score 3):

Apple send this email to all iCloud users:

> Beginning on 15 June, app-specific passwords will be required to
>   access your iCloud data using third-party apps such as Microsoft
>   Outlook, Mozilla Thunderbird, or other mail, contacts and calendar
>   services not provided by Apple.
>
> If you are already signed in to a third-party app using your primary
>   Apple ID password, you will be signed out automatically when this
>   change takes effect. You will need to generate an app-specific
>   password and sign in again.

From 2017-06-15 you are required to use [app-specific passwords](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204397) for third party apps.

**Generate an app-specific password**

1. Sign in to your Apple ID account page. https://appleid.apple.com
2. In the Security section, click Generate Password below App-Specific Passwords.
3. Follow the steps on your screen.

After you generate your app-specific password, enter or paste it into the password field of the app as you would normally.

**Manage app-specific passwords**

You can have up to 25 active app-specific passwords at any given time. If you need to, you can revoke passwords individually or all at once.

1. Sign in to your Apple ID account page. https://appleid.apple.com
2. In the Security section, click Edit.
3. In the App Specific Passwords section, click View History.
4. Click   next to a password you want to delete, or Revoke All.

After you revoke a password, the app using that password will be signed out of your account until you generate a new password and sign in again.

Any time you change or reset your primary Apple ID password, all of your app-specific passwords are revoked automatically to protect the security of your account. You'll need to generate new app-specific passwords for any apps that you want to continue using.

Comment: Talk about bad timing... last week it would have worked.

Comment: `To generate and use app-specific passwords, your Apple ID must be protected with two-factor authentication` and if you haven't enabled a two-factor authentication yet (like me) an Apple's device is required to do so